# Prepopulating Stack Overflow's "ask" form with query params

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to generate a URL for a pre-filled Stack Overflow "Ask Question" form. I see that SO honors the `title` and `tags` query parameters, but I can't figure out how to populate the question body textarea (`#wmd-input`).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=foo&tags=bar&postText=baz

I've tried a few parameter names: body, text, message, post-text, postText, posttext, etc., but no luck. Is it possible?

Comment: Because I'm curious / nosy: what's your use case for pre-populating the question? With a template that needs filling in - or something else?

Comment: Imagine a user is in your FOSS and you want them to be able to ask a support question. Giving them a direct link into stackoverflow with a little pre-populated tag and information about the page they are on, etc. I can understand why this is intentional, but I can also understand the desire for a way to do it.

Comment: Corresponding post on MSO: [Is there a way to pre-fill the body of a new question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385508/1478931)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible?

No, it's not. This is intentional.